# Django js translation gives: warning: unterminated string

Tags: django, translation

I am trying to translate js code in django translation. The problem is, I get a warning saying `unterminated string`, but I could not relate with the warning message. Still, it makes the translation, but there is some irregularity ie, it skips some of the `gettext`.

When I enterred the following command:

```
django-admin makemessages -l ne -d djangojs
```

This is the exception from translator:

> ./static/js/comment.js:356: warning: unterminated string
> processing locale ne

*comment.js*

```
352    edit_div.fadeOut(1000, 'linear', function(){
353        this.remove();
354        if(!($('.comment-of').length)){
355            $("#comments").html('<div class="comment-of no-comment dis-color">'+gettext('No Comment')+'</div>');
356        }
357    });
```